# Why is char.GetNumericValue() giving the wrong result?

Tags: c#, enums, char

I have the following enum

```
public enum Status
{
    New = 'N',
    Live = 'L',
    Expired = 'E'
}
```

And upon receiving the char `'N'` I would like to get the relevant value (i.e. `Status.New`)

It seems that `Enum.Parse` will not work with `char`, or even `char.toString()` for that matter, so I want to get the numeric value associated with the char

```
var myChar = 'N';
var myNumber = Char.GetNumericValue(myChar); // or char.GetNumericValue(myChar);
```

and the value of `myNumber` is `-1`, which is incorrect

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=net-5.0) says that `Char.GetNumericValue()`
*converts a specified numeric Unicode character to a double-precision floating-point number*.

The character 'N' is not numeric, it is an alphabetical character.

If you want to get a `Status` enum value, you could just use:

```
Status status = (Status)myChar;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=net-5.0) says `GetNumericValue()` returns: "The numeric value of c **if that character represents a number**; otherwise, -1.0."
'N' does not represent a number, so it returns -1.

A `char` can be implicitly converted to a number:

```
int number = 'N';
```

Or, if you want to use `var`, you just need an explicit cast.

Note also that your enum values are `int`s, not `char`s. They are implicitly converted.